# Find the optimal coefficient $k$ for an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

There is an inequality as follows：

If $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $t\geq \frac{4}{9}(a+b+c)$,then
$$(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)\leq \left(t-\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3,$$
whith brings me to the following question：

> If for any $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and $t\geq k(a+b+c+d)$,the inequality
> $$(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)\leq \left(t-\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^4$$
> holds,then find the minimum of $k$.

I've tried $k=\frac 1 2$ is satisfying, so $k$ must less than $\frac 1 2$,but how about minimum of $k$ ？

Comment: Numerical experimentation suggests $k=(2+\sqrt2)/8$.

Comment: Is there some way to prove it?@RobPratt

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe if you show your proof for $k=1/2$, it can be refined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**. Find the minimum of $k$ such that
$$(t - a)(t - b)(t - c)(t - d) \le \left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right)^4 \tag{1}$$
holds for all $a, b, c, d \ge 0$ and $t \ge k(a + b + c + d)$.

**Answer**. The minimum of $k$ is $\frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}$.

**Proof**.

When $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4$,
from (1), we know that
$$(t - 1)(t - 2)(t - 3)(t - 4) \le (t - 5/2)^4 \tag{2}$$
holds for all $t \ge 10k$.
Since (2) is not true for $t = 5/2$,
we have $k > 1/4$.

When $a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, d = 1$
and $t = k(a + b + c + d) = 2k$,
from (1), we have
$(2k)^2(2k - 1)^2 \le (2k - 1/2)^4$
or
$2k^2 - k + \frac{1}{16} \ge 0$
which results in (using $k > 1/4$)
$$k \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}.$$

We claim that the minimum of $k$ is $\frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}$.

It suffices to prove that
$$(t - a)(t - b)(t - c)(t - d) \le \left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right)^4 \tag{3}$$
holds for all $a, b, c, d \ge 0$
and $t \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)$.

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c \ge d$.

We split into three cases.

**Case** 1: $t > a$

(3) is true by AM-GM.

**Case** 2: $b \le t \le a$

Since $(t - a)(t - b)(t - c)(t - d) \le 0$, (3) is true.

**Case** 3: $\frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d) \le t < b$

Since $t \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)
\ge \frac{2 + 1}{8}(3c) \ge c$, we have
\begin{align*}
 (t - a)(t - b)(t - c)(t - d)
 &= (a - t)(b - t) \cdot (t - c)(t - d)\\
 &\le \frac{(a - t + b - t)^2}{4}\cdot \frac{(t - c + t - d)^2}{4}.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{(a - t + b - t)^2}{4}\cdot \frac{(t - c + t - d)^2}{4} \le \left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right)^4$$
or
$$\frac{(a + b - 2t)(2t - c - d)}{4} \le \left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right)^2$$
or (simplifying)
$$2\left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right)^2 \ge \frac{(a + b - c - d)^2}{16}$$
or
$$\sqrt 2 \cdot \left(t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right) \ge \frac{a + b - c -d}{4}$$
which is true since $t \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)$ and thus $\sqrt 2 (t - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4})
\ge \frac{1}{4} (a + b + c + d)$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice again ! Two comments: a) the case 3 may not even exist, for situations where $\frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d) \ge b$. What happens then? b) if case 3 exists, it must also include the equality case which requires $t = t_0 = \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)$ and hence  $\sqrt 2 \cdot \left(t_0 - \frac{a + b + c + d}{4}\right) =  \frac{a + b + c + d}{4} = \frac{a + b - c -d}{4}$. This is true for $(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,0,0)$. However, the equality case only appears for  $(a,b,c,d) = (b,b,0,0)$. The condition $a=b$ makes the earlier used AM-GM tight, for $a \ne b$ it's even stronger.

Comment: @Andreas $t \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)$. So if $\frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d) \ge b$, it holds that $t \ge b$ which belongs to case 1 or 2.

Comment: @Andreas Or $S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3$ ($S_3$ is not empty, e.g. $a=b=1, c= d = 0$): $$S= \{(a, b, c, d, t) : a \ge b \ge c \ge d \ge 0; t \ge \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)\}$$

$$S_1 = \{(a, b, c, d, t) : a \ge b \ge c \ge d \ge 0; t > a\}$$

$$S_2 = \{(a, b, c, d, t) : a \ge b \ge c \ge d \ge 0; b \le t \le a\}$$

$$S_3 = \{(a, b, c, d, t) : a \ge b \ge c \ge d \ge 0; \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d) \le t < b\}$$

Comment: @Andreas When $c = d = 0$ and $t = t_0 = \frac{2 + \sqrt 2}{8}(a + b + c + d)$, (3) becomes ${\frac {1}{128}}\, \left( 3+2\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^
{2} \left( a+b \right) ^{2}$. So equality case is $a = b$.

Comment: Perfect, it's a creative answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Some thoughts, too long for a comment.*

This is a pretty nice question.

Let's start with the easier case, to see what is required:

To prove that $f = \left(t-\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3 - (t-a)(t-b)(t-c) \ge 0$ holds for $t\geq \frac{4}{9}(a+b+c)$ one can proceed by opening the brackets in $f$, which gives a linear equation in $t$, and setting $t= k (a+b+c)$, which results in
$$
f = k (a+b+c) [\frac13 (a+b+c)^2 - (ab +bc + ac)] + abc - \frac{1}{27} (a+b+c)^3 \ge 0 
$$
Now this is a homogeneous expression and one has to inspect for which $(a,b,c)$ the largest $k$ is required, which will be the case (in hindsight, or by experimentation) for $(a,b,c) =(x,x,0)$ and permutations. Hence, to continue proving, an  auxiliary inequality is required which is tight for these points. This is given by (well,  it also has to be proved, which can be done by Schur ... ,  see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h236406p1301365) and scroll down to Maxim Bogdan's post)
$$
(a+b+c)^3 + 9  abc \ge  4 (a+b+c)(ab + ac + bc)
$$
which in fact is tight even for $(a,b,c) =(x,x,0)$ (with permutations) and $(a,b,c) =(x,x,x)$. Using this auxiliary inequality to bound $abc$  gives

\begin{align}
f   \ge &  k (a+b+c) [\frac13 (a+b+c)^2 - (ab +bc + ac)] + \frac49 [(a+b+c)(ab + ac + bc) - \frac{1}{3} (a+b+c)^3 ]\\
 = &   [k - \frac49] [(a+b+c) [\frac13 (a+b+c)^2 - (ab +bc + ac)]
\end{align}

Since $\frac13 (a+b+c)^2 - (ab +bc + ac) \ge 0$, we require $k =  \frac49$, as already stated in OP's question.

Now let's draw the analogies to the inequality which is being asked for, i.e.
$f =  \left(t-\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^4 - (t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d) \ge 0$. Again opening  the brackets gives a quadratic equation in $t$. Setting $t= k (a+b+c+d)$ gives  a homogeneous equation (quadratic in $k$) and one has to inspect for which $(a,b,c,d)$ the largest $k$ is required. By experimentation, this will be the case for $(a,b,c,d) =(x,x,0,0)$ and permutations. Then, the  resulting quadratic equation becomes positive for $k = \frac{2+\sqrt2}{8}$, as already stated by RobPratt. Hence, in analogy to the above discussion:

- find a homogenous auxiliary inequality in $(a,b,c,d)$ which is tight for  $(a,b,c,d) =(x,x,0,0)$ and permutations.
- use this to factor the quadratic equation $f(k)$ such that the conclusion for $k$ can be drawn
- to do so, standard quadratic curve discussion techniques can be used.
- it is easy to prove that the quadratic equation $f(k)$ always has positive leading factor $\propto k^2$, and that it won't have zeroes for all constellations $(a,b,c,d)$.

So far my comments for *"paving  the way"*. Bonne chance!